# background image and body float not working

Tags: html, jquery, image, background-image

I am very confused, and I know that none of the "feeds" I've seen (yet) relate to my issue.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Creating a Proper HTML/PHP/CSS Project
        </title>
        
        <!-- Links to jQuery and JavaScript files -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                
        <!-- Links to external CSS stylesheets -->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    
        <!-- Internal Styles (if necessary) -->
        <style>
            /* Internal styles go here */
        </style>
        <!--[if IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header>
                <h1>Learning to Build a Proper Web Site with HTML, PHP, and CSS</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lessons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">References</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            
            <section class="content">
                <article>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/html.jpg" alt="Client-side Programming" class="article_img">
                        <figcaption>
                            Client-side Programming
                        </figcaption>
                           
                        
                    </figure>
                    <hgroup>
                       <h2>What is Client-side Programming?</h2> 
                       <h3>And Client-side Languages</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        
                        /*    window.onload = function() {
                                if (window.jQuery) {
                                    // jQuery is loaded
                                    alert("Yeah!");
                                } else {
                                    // jQuery is not loaded
                                    alert("Doesn't Work");
                                }
                            } CHECKS TO SEE IF JQUERY IS LOADED */ 
                                                
                        $('button').click(function() {
                            
                            $('#hide').show(fast);
                            
                        }); 
                    </script>
                    <button>Click</button>
                    <p id="hide" style="display: none;">Hide this text by pushing the button</p>
                    <p class="indent">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    
                </article>
                
                <article>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/php.jpg" alt="Server-side Programming" class="article_img">
                        <figcaption>
                            Server-side Programming
                        </figcaption>
                           
                        
                    </figure>
                    
                    <hgroup>
                       <h2>Article 2</h2> 
                       <h3>Subtitle</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <p class="indent">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                 
                </article>
            </section> <!-- End content section -->
            
            <aside>
                <section class="popular-topic">
                    <h2>Topic Tops</h2>
                    <a href="#">Lesson 1: Editor, IDE, and the "Hello, World" program (FRONTEND)</a>
                    <a href="#">Lesson 2: Linking to CSS and JS files (FRONTEND)</a>
                    <a href="#">Lesson 3: Server-side scripts and MySQL (BACKEND)</a>
                    <a href="#">Lesson 4: PROJECT! CREATE A SOCIAL MEDIA PLATFORM! (BACK- AND FRONTEND) </a>
                    <p>So who's ready to embark on the journey of a lifetime? These lessons, realistically, are designed for those just starting out with code, and those who are still learning. If you are a know-it-all yuppy, please move to the next site. Thanks!</p>
                </section>
                <section class="popular-topic">
                    <h2>Topic Tops</h2>
                    <p>Paragragh</p>    
                </section>
            </aside>
            
            <footer>
                &copy; 2020 | Magdi Kanaan | Free Coding Lessons
            </footer>
            
        </div> <!-- End page div -->
    </body>
    
</html>
<?php
//TODO, Separate header and footer into respective php files. (i.e. header.php and footer.php)

?>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```css
/* STYLES - CSS File */

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, figure, figcaption {
    display: block;
}

body {
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #f9f8f6;
    background: url("img/bg.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px;
}

.page {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
}

header {
    height: 160px;
 /* background-image: url('img/#.jpg') */
}

h1 {
    /* text-indent: -9999px; */
    width: 940px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav, footer {
    clear: both;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #aeaca8;
    height: 30px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 30px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav li a:hover, nav li a.current {
    color: #000000;
}

section.content {
    float: left;
    width: 659px;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

article {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.article_img {
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
}

hgroup {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

figure {
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

figcaption {
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
}

aside {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

aside section a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

aside section a:hover {
    color: #985d6a;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
a {
    color: #de6581;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
    margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: #de6581;
}

aside h2 {
    padding: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: #de6581;
}

footer {
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 7px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

My layout should look like this:

[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTHvk.jpg)

I got this code straight out of a coding book and somehow its not working! Another weird thing is that my jQuery is loaded, but not working. Something is definitely wrong.

But I must say, The header image and background image I am using are different than the ones in the "desired effect" image.

Simply put, the body won't "center-margin" (`margin: 0 auto`) and my background url (which is correct) wont display. Why? I'm so confused.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question with a description of the issue, rather than relying on an image to convey the issue. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for assistance.

Comment: I did at the bottom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery isn't working because you're missing quotation marks around the show argument.

```js
$('button').click(function() {

   $('#hide').show("fast");

});
```

I replaced your images with placeholders, and that's working. Maybe check you path again.

```js
$('button').click(function() {

          $('#hide').show("fast");

});
```

```css
/* STYLES - CSS File */

header,
section,
footer,
aside,
nav,
article,
figure,
figcaption {
  display: block;
}

body {
  color: #666666;
  background-color: #f9f8f6;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500");
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin: 0px;
}

.page {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  height: 160px;
  /* background-image: url('img/#.jpg') */
}

h1 {
  /* text-indent: -9999px; */
  width: 940px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0px;
}

nav,
footer {
  clear: both;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #aeaca8;
  height: 30px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 30px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

nav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav li a:hover,
nav li a.current {
  color: #000000;
}

section.content {
  float: left;
  width: 659px;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

article {
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.article_img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

hgroup {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

figure {
  float: left;
  width: 290px;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: left;
}

aside {
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

aside section a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

aside section a:hover {
  color: #985d6a;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

a {
  color: #de6581;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #de6581;
}

aside h2 {
  padding: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #de6581;
}

footer {
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 7px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <header>
    <h1>Learning to Build a Proper Web Site with HTML, PHP, and CSS</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lessons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">References</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="content">
    <article>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="Client-side Programming" class="article_img">
        <figcaption>
          Client-side Programming
        </figcaption>


      </figure>
      <hgroup>
        <h2>What is Client-side Programming?</h2>
        <h3>And Client-side Languages</h3>
      </hgroup>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        /*    window.onload = function() {
                                        if (window.jQuery) {
                                            // jQuery is loaded
                                            alert("Yeah!");
                                        } else {
                                            // jQuery is not loaded
                                            alert("Doesn't Work");
                                        }
                                    } CHECKS TO SEE IF JQUERY IS LOADED */

        $('button').click(function() {

          $('#hide').show(fast); // Missing quotation marks around fast

        });
      </script>
      <button>Click</button>
      <p id="hide" style="display: none;">Hide this text by pushing the button</p>
      <p class="indent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

    </article>

    <article>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" alt="Server-side Programming" class="article_img">
        <figcaption>
          Server-side Programming
        </figcaption>


      </figure>

      <hgroup>
        <h2>Article 2</h2>
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
      </hgroup>
      <p class="indent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

    </article>
  </section>
  <!-- End content section -->

  <aside>
    <section class="popular-topic">
      <h2>Topic Tops</h2>
      <a href="#">Lesson 1: Editor, IDE, and the "Hello, World" program (FRONTEND)</a>
      <a href="#">Lesson 2: Linking to CSS and JS files (FRONTEND)</a>
      <a href="#">Lesson 3: Server-side scripts and MySQL (BACKEND)</a>
      <a href="#">Lesson 4: PROJECT! CREATE A SOCIAL MEDIA PLATFORM! (BACK- AND FRONTEND) </a>
      <p>So who's ready to embark on the journey of a lifetime? These lessons, realistically, are designed for those just starting out with code, and those who are still learning. If you are a know-it-all yuppy, please move to the next site. Thanks!</p>
    </section>
    <section class="popular-topic">
      <h2>Topic Tops</h2>
      <p>Paragragh</p>
    </section>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    &copy; 2020 | Magdi Kanaan | Free Coding Lessons
  </footer>

</div>
<!-- End page div -->
```

Comment: Looks like I am an idiot, sry fellow-coders! Turns out that i was targeting my id="page" as ".page" instead of "#page" in my CSS, and my path was correct, but since i have IIS7 and AMPPS installed side-by-side, I ran into problems with the "localhost". Also, as mentioned above, I forgot the quotes around my "show" argument in my jQuery! Wow, two days of confusion, and such an easy solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the first mismatch I noticed:

```html
<div id="page">
```

```css
.page {
```

In CSS, you'd style an `id="page"` like this:

```css
#page {
```